# Evaluating $\int \frac {\ln(3x+7)}{x^2}\mathrm dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

How to evaluate the following integral?

$$\int \frac {\ln(3x+7)}{x^2}\,\mathrm dx$$

I tried substituting both $u = 3x+7$ and $u = \ln(3x+7)$, but the resulting integral seems to be much more complex. I also considered integration by parts, but didn't start because it seemed useless in this case.

The substitution $t = -\dfrac 1x$ was promising, because I could get rid of $\dfrac 1{x^2}$ and remained with $\ln\left(-\dfrac3t+7\right)$, but then I did not know how to proceed.

Comment: Did you try integration by parts to get rid of the logarithm ? This would be simpler I guess. Continue with partial fraction decomposition.

Comment: I considered it but then didn't proceed. I realise now that it may be the way to go.

Comment: Yes, it is ! Cheers :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x = \frac{1}{t}$

$$I = -\int \log(3 + 7t) - \log(t) dt$$

The rest is simple.

Your first thought was actually good.

Comment: Aw, I feel so dumb. I had forgotten logarithms' properties...

Comment: How do you go from the  integral given in the post to your ? Substituting $x=\frac 1t$ does not seem to lead to your proposed form. But, for sure, I may be totally wrong. Cheers :-)

Comment: The task is to simplify. After simplification, it does indeed lead to the proper answer.

Comment: This works, but you'd have to IBP for both of those log expression, so I think IBP at the beginning is easier

Comment: Not really. We can simply use the integral table for $\log$ instead of IBP.

Comment: Using the table feels like cheating to me, so I don't do it. But if you say so.

Answer (score 1):

It turned out integration by parts was the way to go. I'll post here my solution in case someone needs it.

Recall the integration by parts formula:
$$\int u\,\mathrm dv = uv - \int v\,\mathrm du$$

In this case $u = \ln(3x+7)$, and $\mathrm dv = 1/x^2\,\mathrm dx$.

Hence:
$$\require{cancel}
\begin{align}\int\frac 1{x^2}\ln(3x+7)\,\mathrm dx &= -\frac 1x\ln(3x+7) + \int\frac 1x\cdot\frac 3{3x + 7}\,\mathrm dx =\\
&=-\frac{\ln(3x+7)}x + 3\left(\frac 17\int\frac 1x\,\mathrm dx - \frac 1{\cancel{3}} \cdot \frac {\cancel{3}}7\int\frac{3}{3x + 7}\,\mathrm dx\right ) =\\
&= -\frac{\ln(3x+7)}x + \frac 37\ln x - \frac 37 \ln|3x + 7| + C =\\
&= \frac{-7\ln(3x + 7) + 3x\ln x - 3x\ln|3x + 7|}{7x} + C =\\
&= \frac{3x\ln x - (3x + 7)\ln(3x + 7)}{7x} + C
\end{align}$$

Comment: You almost made it ! There is a sign error in the last line. Cheers :-)

Comment: You are welcome !